# Можно наложить одну картинку на другую картинку внутри imageview?

Tags: android

Можно ли наложить одну картинку на другую внутри одного imageView???

Comment: вы хотите сделать одну картинку прозрачнее чем другая, чтобы в итоге выглядело как будто она находится под картинкой?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, я хотел бы просто одну картинку наложить на другую в одном imageView. (Ну да то что вы сказали)

Comment: а у вас есть прозрачная картинка или вы хотите эту картинку делать прозрачной уже в программе?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko прозрачная

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, только надо много картинок так сделать. А не только 2

Comment: это значит что в одном imageview будет не две картинки а больше?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, да. Такое возможно? то чтобы помещалось 2 картинки можно использовать setImageBitmap и setBackgroundResource.

Comment: Кол-во картинок известно или оно динамически меняется? Можно хоть на Canvas'e их добавлять и рисовать в одной ImageView

Comment: @RomanK., кстати так тоже можно))) чисто как вариант можно уже загружать в приложение готовые картинки и ставить на фон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно будет использовать два или больше `imageview` один с прозрачной картинкой а второй с обычной и дальше уже как нужно, и дальше уже поместить в разметке макет `FrameLayout` где у вас будут размещены ваши виджеты. Начинаем все просто, тот который самый первый то есть самый нижний, будет висеть самым последним в контейнере:

```
FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/t" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</FrameLayout>
```

это пример, вам уже нужно делать с вашим ресурсом который вы будете использовать. Вот [первоисточник](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26729715/set-an-imageview-over-another-imageview-xml) .

Либо есть второй вариант который вы упомянули - `setImageBitmap` и `setBackgroundResource`. Но я не очень уверен что он будет работать так как вам нужно, потому что второй способ подразумевает использование только двух картинок насколько я понимаю, а вам нужно больше чем две.

Надеюсь что я хоть чем-то помог в решении вашей задачи, если все еще остались вопросы или вы столкнулись со сложностями, то не стесняйтесь и пишите, помогу чем смогу. Удачи :)

Comment: Это почти отвечает на мой вопрос(Я говорил только про 1 imageView). Я был согласен и на просто НЕТ. Но большое спасибо за пример.

Comment: не очень понимаю если честно)) вам  же нужно каким-то образом сделать две картинки в одной, или вообще еще больше, а так то получается что вам нужно чтобы выглядело определенным образом, а для этого нужно будет немного поковыряться)